# Where to get the value for correct CSRF token to include in headers of consequent requests in Angular (Backend: Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, angular, csrf, csrf-token

I am working in a project building application using Angular 7 and Node.js. I need to implement protection against CSRF.

I have used `cookie-parser` and `csurf` npm packages in my Node.js (Express) code. So, as expected, now I can see that in each response header there is a `set-cookie` header having different values for `csrf`, also there is a `_csrf` browser cookie being set having a different value. And I have included a `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header for each of the subsequent requests from Angular.

But the problem is that I am unable to figure out which value to send in the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header. I have tried with the value of `_csrf` browser cookie as well as the different `csrf` values from the `set-cookie` response headers of previous requests. None worked for me. I am always getting an error saying '**invalid csrf token**'.

Please help me with which value I should include as CSRF token in the subsequent request headers so that there is no error.